# How can I build a multi-column layout with a Knockout foreach?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I've included a code snippet which demonstrates the problem I'm trying to solve.  I'm trying to build a two column layout based upon the data within an `observableArray`.  I've tried using the Knockout `if` bindings, but that doesn't work well within the `foreach`.  This seems like it should be very simple, but for some reason I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work within the realm of Knockout.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.People = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h4>Current</h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="foreach: People">
        <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Desired</h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to transform your data into a matrix `[[1,2], [3, 4], [5]]`. Then loop once for rows and inside it loop on the columns. _Or_ stop using bootstrap here and write your own CSS. A simple `.col { float: left; width: 50%;}` rule on that `p` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="foreach: People">
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 2 == 0 -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" data-bind="text: $parent.People()[$index()]"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" data-bind="text: $parent.People()[$index()+1]"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb07dc26/)